# TTS Watson adding silence between sentences or words

Tags: text-to-speech, ibm-watson

I have been trying to add few seconds of silence between words or sentences in Watson. I tried adding a series of dots to the string but that did not seem to work, but that would be too easy. I dont see anything on the API that would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SSML markup to indicate breaks.  Here's an example (3s = 3 seconds):

```
    String text = "<speak version='1.0'>This is some text <break time='3s'/>" + 
        "This is some more text</speak>";
```

Or you can use `<break strength='weak'/>` instead - there are several settings for `strength=`. Check out https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/text-to-speech/SSML.shtml

Here's the Java SDK call you would make with the above:

```
InputStream stream = service.synthesize(text, Voice.EN_MICHAEL, AudioFormat.OGG_VORBIS).execute();
```

Comment: Btw, your example helped me out in figuring the code for python. Just reviewing now... a year some later:)